# Plantronics .Audio 995 Wireless USB: Hiss?

Tags: audio, headset, wireless-headset

I've just bought a Plantronics .Audio 995 Wireless USB, as a replacement for the Audio 400 DSP Foldable PC Headset I usually use for dictation. (The 400 is great, but I've had 3 break in 3 years.)

The 995 is working well, except that there is a constant hiss, even with volume turned down to the minimum. Does anyone know if this is normal? Or is mine defective? (Whichever way, the hiss essentially makes it unusable!)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally mine has no such issue (using for 2+ years). There is some garbling of audio sometimes when it looses and re–establishes wireless connection, but no hiss as described.